# Getting a DuplicateFileException when adding a module to my Android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, mqtt

I am trying to add the [Paho MQTT](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android) service (and client) to my Android app, but I am running into a `com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException` runtime exception, when running my app.

It **appears** to me that everything is setup right, and when I clean/build, I get no errors at all.

My **app** *build.gradle* file looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: '../org.eclipse.paho.android/service/libs', excludes: ["org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar"], include: '')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs', excludes: ["*org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar"])
    compile (project(':org.eclipse.paho.android.service')){
        // exclude module: "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3"
        transitive=true
    }

    // Uncommenting the below (when commenting out the above) WORKS.
    //   However, I need to be able to alter the source, to I do need to be able 
    //   to import the Paho MQTT service as a module to my app.
    // compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    // compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'

    ...
```

However, when I run, I receive a `DuplicateFileException` exception:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/nls/messages_zh_TW.properties
    File1: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.1.0/89d827ffa47c241f2627421ef1d6c7a8c207a341/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar
    File2: /Users/me/myapp/code/myapp-android/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/build/intermediates/bundles/default/classes.jar
```

My file hierarchy looks like:

[image]

which appears ok to me.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to resolve this? The error claims that `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar` is clashing with `classes.jar`, but my gradle file explicitly excludes the compiling of `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar` (or so I think it does).

I'm at a loss here; any pointers are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because two of your dependencies are using Eclipse Paho MQTT library.

Following should fix the issue

Add following to your app level gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
}

compile("one-of-your-dependency:1.0.0"){
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.paho'
}
```